# Setting up a database link between Oracle and Snowflake

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dblink

Has anyone implemented a successful database link between Oracle and Snowflake databases before?

I am using an ODBC to connect to the Snowflake data in question and the connection works. I can setup a python script and query the data, getting returns as expected.

I found [this article with guidance on what to do](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/snowflake-odbc-oracle-hs.rst), but after following that and the Snowflake documentation, Oracle is returning errors:

```
[Error] Execution (9: 20): ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
ORA-02063: preceding line from TEST
```

The preceding lines are the dblink:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK TEST
CONNECT TO <snowflake_username>
IDENTIFIED BY <snowflake_password>
USING <tnsnames_address>;
```

If anyone has done this before and ran into issues or has guidance on configuration that's different with Snowflake than other Oracle dblinks, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dg4odbc would be a good tool for this. First get the odbc config right and test verify with isql. The heterogeneous services part is always a bit fuzzy. References to drivers should use the driver manager.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a fair bit of debugging to get working and would say you need pretty good Oracle, ODBC and Unix
knowledge, but main details and examples of my config below from a test box I have.

I'll try to do a more detailed write up when I get some spare time.

select database_name from information_schema.databases@mysnowflakedb;

DATABASE_NAME

---

DEMO_DB

INTL_DB

SMEW

SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA

UTIL_DB

0. install RPM and dependencies

su -
rpm -i ./SnowflakeODBCDriverforUnix.rpm
yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel

1. Activate a 30-day trial license: in /opt/cdata/cdata-odbc-driver-for-snowflake/bin

./install-license.x64

2. create DB LINK on Oracle db:

CREATE DATABASE LINK mysnowflakedb CONNECT TO test IDENTIFIED BY Test1234 USING 'mysnowflakedb';

OWNER      DB_LINK      USERNAME         HOST         CREATED

---

PSAMMY     MYSNOWFLAKEDB    TEST             mysnowflakedb    09-SEP-21

2. update odbc.ini :  located in /etc

[ODBC Data Sources]

CData Snowflake Sys = CData ODBC Driver for Snowflake

[CData Snowflake Sys]

Driver= /opt/cdata/cdata-odbc-driver-for-snowflake/lib/libsnowflakeodbc.x64.so

url=https://xx12345.canada-central.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

user=test

password=Test1234

Database=DEMO_DB

Warehouse=COMPUTE_WH

RoleName=SYSADMIN

3. update odbcinst.ini : located in /etc

[ODBC Drivers]

CData ODBC Driver for Snowflake=Installed

[CData ODBC Driver for Snowflake]

Description = CData ODBC Driver for Snowflake

Driver64 = /opt/cdata/cdata-odbc-driver-for-snowflake/lib/libsnowflakeodbc.x64.so

4. create initmysnowflakedb.ora : located in <ORACLE_HOME>/hs/admin

HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = "CData Snowflake Sys"

HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF

HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /opt/cdata/cdata-odbc-driver-for-snowflake/lib/libsnowflakeodbc.x64.so

set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini

5. update listener.ora : located in /network/admin

I created a dedicated lister for ODBC details below

LISTENER_ODBC =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac01-A.localdomain)(PORT = 1511))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1511))
)
)

SID_LIST_LISTENER_ODBC =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC = (SID_NAME = mysnowflakedb) (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.6.0/db_3 )
(ENV="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cdata/cdata-odbc-driver-for-snowflake/lib:/u01/app/oracle/product/19.6.0/db_3/lib") (PROGRAM = dg4odbc))
)

#start listener
lsnrctl start listener_odbc

6. update  tnsnames.ora : located in /network/admin

mysnowflakedb  = (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST = rac01-a.localdomain )(PORT=1511)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysnowflakedb)) (HS=OK))